# Creating a Windows XP Junction

Tags: java, windows

I need to create a Junction point (directory symbolic link) from C:\x to C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\aaa\bbb since I am running up against the Windows XP maximum file path length when adding files to this directory and I have no control over the directory structure.

I was reading that creating Junction points is not built-in to Windows so I will need a tool or software library to do it. How can I create a Junction point in code? I was looking at using [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768), but legal is telling me that I [cannot distribute](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb847944) it.

My codebase is primarily in Java. I would prefer to not introduce C/C++ to do this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not built into Windows? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524

Comment: Thanks, but that link is for Windows 2000. I do not know of an exe/bat in Windows XP.

Comment: NTFS hasn't changed in a long while. linkd.exe may not work on a 64bit windows, but there's no reason it shouldn't work on any 32bit version of xp/vista/7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) had the right idea but did not post an answer so I will post this one.
This Windows article details the `linkd` utility: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524/en-us

> Linkd.exe
>
> - Grafts any target folder onto a Windows 2000 version of NTFS folder

This EXE can be download via Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd

Although it is for Windows 2003, it will install with no problems on Windows XP. Note that this kit is not compatible with Vista and Vista already has a built-in utility (`mklink`) for creating Junction points.

One installed, a Junction can can be created:

```
linkd C:\x C:\xxx\yyy\zzz\aaa\bbb
```

Comment: mklink already in Windows 7 as well. `MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target`

Comment: The problem with mklink is, that there is no mklink.exe. (Meaning: You won't find it in your path, because it is built into cmd.exe.) Otoh, something like

    cmd.exe /c mklink /j <junction_to_create> <actual_dir>

might work.

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source (MIT license) tool named **"ln-win"** that should fit your requirements:

http://neosmart.net/blog/2011/open-source-100-compatible-ln-for-windows-and-junction-point-library/

https://github.com/NeoSmart/ln-win

**Update:** Unfortunately this tool does not work on Windows XP, it requires Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 2008 or higher.

Comment: The website says it only works for Vista/7 and does not mention XP. When I try to run it in XP, I get an error: "The procedure entry point CreateSymbolicLinkW could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll."

Answer (score 0):

The problem with mklink is, that there is no mklink.exe. (Meaning: You won't find it in your path, because it is built into cmd.exe.) Otoh, something like

```
cmd.exe /c mklink /j <junction_to_create> <actual_dir>
```

might work.